# ArrayAdapter error when database is empty

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to adapt my data from my SQLite database to my ListView, when the table has some lines, there is no problem, but when I delete all the inserts from the table, I have an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()' on a null object reference
```

My adapter's code:

```
public class AdapterTop extends ArrayAdapter<Top> {
    private LayoutInflater mInflat;
    private ArrayList<Top> top = new ArrayList<Top>();
    private int mVRessId;

    public AdapterTop (Context context, int ressId, ArrayList<Top> topu){

        super(context,ressId,topu);
        this.top =topu;
        mInflat = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mVRessId =ressId;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertedView, ViewGroup parents){
        convertedView = mInflat.inflate(mVRessId,null);

        Top topu = top.get(position);
        if (topu != null) {
            TextView name = (TextView) convertedView.findViewById(R.id.txtnomp);
            TextView nbre = (TextView) convertedView.findViewById(R.id.txtnbre);

            if (name != null) {
                name.setText("" + topu.getNom() + ": " + topu.getPrenom());
            }
            if (nbre != null) {
                nbre.setText(String.valueOf(+topu.getNum()));
            }

        }
        return convertedView;

        }


}
```

The function used to return the cursor:

```
public Cursor topuser(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();;
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery("Select U." +KEY_NOM+ ", U." +KEY_PRENOM+ ", count (A." +KEY_MATRICULE+ " ) FROM " +TABLE_ANSWER+ " A, "+TABLE_USER+ " U where U." +KEY_MATRICULE+ " = A." +KEY_MATRICULE+ " LIMIT 3",null );
        return data;
    }
```

My main java code:

```
ArrayList<Top> users;
    Top top;
    mCsr = openhelper.topuser();
            int rows = mCsr.getCount();

        if (rows == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(Kpis.this, "no users", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {

            while (mCsr.moveToNext()) {

                top = new Top(mCsr.getString(0).toString(), mCsr.getString(1).toString(), mCsr.getInt(2));
                users.add(top);

            }
            AdapterTop adapttop = new AdapterTop(this, R.layout.activity_template_top_users, users);
            mListView.setAdapter(adapttop);
        }
```

Is there any problem with that? I did the condition if (rows == 0) tu avoid this but still have the same problem.

The Top classe is made like that:

```
public class Top {
    private String nom;
    private String prenom;
    private int num;

    public Top(String nom, String prenom, int num) {
        this.nom = nom;
        this.prenom = prenom;
        this.num = num;
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public String getPrenom() {
        return prenom;
    }

    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }
}
```

I tried to initiate the top when creating it but didn't work.

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice this one:
                top = new Top(mCsr.getString(0).toString(), mCsr.getString(1).toString(), mCsr.getInt(2));

Comment: Note that `mCsr.getString(0).toString()` can be reduced to `mCsr.getString(0)`. As noted in the answer, you still need to be careful of `null` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I did the condition if (rows == 0) tu avoid this but still have the same problem.

It'll prevent you getting an out of bounds exception, but probably when you saved your data, the columns were nullable. So do you have records, but this record have some field null.

At this point:

```
top = new Top(mCsr.getString(0).toString(), mCsr.getString(1).toString(), mCsr.getInt(2));
```

You are calling `toString()` on something you do know what.
So the easy way to handle this error would be:

```
String noum = "";
if(mCsr.getString(0) != null){
    noum = mCsr.getString(0).toString()
}

String preNoum = "";
if(mCsr.getString(1) != null){
    preNoum = mCsr.getString(1).toString()
}
top = new Top(noum, preNoum, mCsr.getInt(2));
```

You could improve your code with some patterns, but it'll do the trick.

Comment: it worked, I had also to do the same for the int statement.

Comment: There is no need to call toString() since getString() already returns a String